# Count animation up to down when using CountDownTimer class

Tags: android, animation

I want my countdown text animate up to down when counting like GIF file attached bellow. currently it animate like normal fade. I use `CountDownTimer` class to count and a `TextView` for timer. Here is code below:

```
//somecode
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CountText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.countText);
    CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(15000,1000);
    timer.start();
}
```

**CounterClass.java**

```
 public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {

     public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
         super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
     }

     @Override
     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         millis = millisUntilFinished;
         String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
         System.out.println(hms);

         CountText.setText(hms);
      }

      @Override
      public void onFinish() {

      }

   }
```

Is there any way i can achieve this? Been trying to get past 2 days. I know there is solution by creating 4 different text and animate but i cant use it because of some reason. so Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: try this tutorial http://www.androidplus.org/2015/03/android-stopwatch-timer-app-tutorial-15.html

Comment: Check these views [CountdownView](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2641), [CountDownView](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3201)

Comment: all those animation are fade i want up to down animations

Comment: Any good solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone still looking for answer to this.

[Try](https://github.com/hanks-zyh/HTextView) this Library

You can get the desired animation using this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I hope this will help you. I use TranslateAnimation and CountDownTimer

```
         private lateinit var countDownTimer: CountDownTimer
         private lateinit var tvTime:TextView

         tvTime = findViewById(R.id.tv_time)

         val animation = TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, -50.0f, 0.0f)
         animation.duration = 80

        countDownTimer =  object : CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {  
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                tvTime.startAnimation(animation)
                tvTime.text ="${ millisUntilFinished / 1000 }"

            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                tvTime.text = "Done!"
               
            }
        }


        countDownTimer.start()
```

Answer (score -4):

I'm not sure if it's the best method but you can try.

Create multiple TextViews for each character of the timer.
Then in your countdownTimer's onTick check which all characters(seconds or minutes) are changing and add animation to those TextViews.

Comment: Please have a look on Question before answer. i did mention i cant use multiple Textviews. Thanks